# How to sort a matrix/data.frame by all columns

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I have a matrix, e.g.:

```
a = rep(0:1, each=4)
b = rep(rep(0:1, each=2), 2)
c = rep(0:1, times=4)
mat = cbind(c,b,a)
```

I need to sort all columns of this matrix. I know how to do this by sorting specific columns (i.e. a limited number of columns).

```
mat[order(mat[,"c"],mat[,"b"],mat[,"a"]),]
     c b a
[1,] 0 0 0
[2,] 0 0 1
[3,] 0 1 0
[4,] 0 1 1
[5,] 1 0 0
[6,] 1 0 1
[7,] 1 1 0
[8,] 1 1 1
```

However, I need a generic way of doing this without calling any column names, because I could have any number of columns. How can I sort by a large number of columns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a concise solution:

```
mat[do.call(order,as.data.frame(mat)),];
##      c b a
## [1,] 0 0 0
## [2,] 0 0 1
## [3,] 0 1 0
## [4,] 0 1 1
## [5,] 1 0 0
## [6,] 1 0 1
## [7,] 1 1 0
## [8,] 1 1 1
```

The call to `as.data.frame()` converts the matrix to a data.frame in the intuitive way, i.e. each matrix column becomes a list component in the new data.frame. From that, you can effectively pass each matrix column to a single invocation of `order()` by passing the listified form of the matrix as the second argument of `do.call()`.

This will work for any number of columns.

---

It's not a dumb question. The reason that `mat[order(as.data.frame(mat)),]` does not work is because `order()` does *not* order data.frames by row.

Instead of returning a row order for the data.frame based on ordering the column vectors from left to right (which is what my solution does), it basically flattens the data.frame to a single big vector and orders that.

So, in fact, `order(as.data.frame(mat))` is equivalent to `order(mat)`, as a matrix is treated as a flat vector as well.

For your particular data, this returns 24 indexes, which could theoretically be used to index (as a vector) the original matrix `mat`, but since in the expression `mat[order(as.data.frame(mat)),]` you're trying to use them to index just the row dimension of `mat`, some of the indexes are past the highest row index, so you get a "subscript out of bounds" error.

See [`?do.call`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/do.call.html).

I don't think I can explain it better than the help page; take a look at the examples, play with them until you get how it works. Basically, you need to call it when the arguments you want to pass to a single invocation of a function are trapped inside a list.

You can't pass the list itself (because then you're not passing the intended arguments, you're passing a list *containing* the intended arguments), so there must be a primitive function that "unwraps" the arguments from the list for the function call.

This is a common primitive in programming languages where functions are first-class objects, notably (besides R's `do.call()`) JavaScript's [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), Python's (deprecated) [`apply()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply), and vim's [`call()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#call()).

Comment: I hope this is not a dumb question: Could you please explain why "mat[order(as.data.frame(mat)), ]" is not working? I just don't quite get "do.call()". When should I consider using it?