# How to sort a data.table using a target vector

Tags: r, data.table

So, I have the following data.table

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,2,3))

> DT
   x y
1: b 1
2: b 2
3: b 3
4: a 1
5: a 2
6: a 3
7: c 1
8: c 2
9: c 3
```

And I have the following vector

```
k <- c("2","3","1")
```

I want to use `k` as a target vector to sort `DT` using `y` and get something like this.

```
> DT
   x y
1: b 2
2: a 2
3: c 2
4: b 3
5: a 3
6: c 3
7: b 1
8: a 1
9: c 1
```

Any ideas? If I use `DT[order(k)]` I get a subset of the original data, and that isn't what I am looking for.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Throw a call to `match()` in there.

```
DT[order(match(y, as.numeric(k)))]
#    x y
# 1: b 2
# 2: a 2
# 3: c 2
# 4: b 3
# 5: a 3
# 6: c 3
# 7: b 1
# 8: a 1
# 9: c 1
```

Actually `DT[order(match(y, k))]` would work as well, but it is probably safest to make the arguments to `match()` of the same class just in case.

**Note:** `match()` is known to be sub-optimal in some cases.  If you have a large number of rows, you may want to switch to `fastmatch::fmatch` for faster matching.

Comment: How would one go about using this logic to sort multiple columns using target vector `k`?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,2,3))
k <- c("2","3","1")
setkey(DT,y)
DT[data.table(as.numeric(k))]
```

or (from the comment of Richard)

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,2,3))
k <- c("2","3","1")
DT[data.table(y = as.numeric(k)), on = "y"]
```

Comment: Nowadays you can just do `DT[data.table(y = as.numeric(k)), on = "y"]` to merge on `y` and not have to set a key

Answer (score 0):

I wondered if the method proposed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34684973/4524755) (using `order` and `match`) was possible to extend to sort multiple columns using a target vector. I came up with the following and just wanted to post it as it might be useful for others too.

It is a bit unwieldly and perhaps someone who is smarter has better and more concise way to do it?

```r
library(data.table)
set.seed(42L)
DT <- data.table(
  x = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3), 
  y = sample(letters[1:3], 9, TRUE),
  z = c(1, 2, 3)
)

k <- c("b", "a", "c")

x <- DT[, lapply(.SD, match, table = k), .SDcols = c("x", "y")]

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/29483058/4524755
ii <- do.call(order, x)

DT[ii]
#>    x y z
#> 1: b b 2
#> 2: b b 3
#> 3: b a 1
#> 4: a a 1
#> 5: a a 2
#> 6: a a 3
#> 7: c b 1
#> 8: c a 2
#> 9: c c 3
```

A second method could be to convert columns to a `factor` and setting the `levels` to `k`. Then sorting by both columns. This could be achieved using `set*` functions. Something along the lines of;

```r
# method2
DT2 <- copy(DT)

for(col in c("x", "y")) {
  set(DT2, j = col, value = factor(DT[[col]], levels = k))  
}

setorderv(DT2, col = c("x", "y"))
DT2
#>    x y z
#> 1: b b 2
#> 2: b b 3
#> 3: b a 1
#> 4: a a 1
#> 5: a a 2
#> 6: a a 3
#> 7: c b 1
#> 8: c a 2
#> 9: c c 3
```