# Sort matrix column in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have a matrix (x) with a few columns and rows of the following form:

```
2 5 3 6 4
3 6 4 2 5
4 2 5 3 6
```

I want sort columns ascending `apply(x,2,sort)`and later sort columns ascending the average in column.

The output would look like this:

```
2 2 3 2 3 
3 3 4 5 5
4 6 5 6 6
```

Data

```
x <- structure(c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6), .Dim = c(3L, 5L))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by `later sort columns ascending the average in column.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a matrix/data.frame by all columns in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482983/how-to-sort-a-matrix-data-frame-by-all-columns-in-r)

Comment: This isn't duplicate, I think.
I have to calculate the average in each column, next sort columns ascending.

Comment: Your expected output still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oh, sorry very much, but firsr matrix wasn't corrent, I corrected it, thanks for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
A <- matrix(c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6), ncol=5)
B <- apply(A, 2, sort)
C <- B[, order(apply(B, 2, sum), decreasing = FALSE)]

> C
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    2    3    2    4
[2,]    3    3    4    5    6
[3,]    4    6    5    6    6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your matrix

```
mat <- matrix(c(2,5, 3, 6, 4,3 ,6 ,4 ,2 ,6, 4 ,2 ,5, 3, 6), byrow=T, nrow=3, ncol = 5)
mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] 
[1,]    2    5    3    6    4
[2,]    3    6    4    2    6
[3,]    4    2    5    3    6
```

Sort the columns in ascending fashion

```
mat_colsort <- apply(mat,2,sort)
mat_colsort
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    2    3    2    4
[2,]    3    5    4    3    6
[3,]    4    6    5    6    6
```

Get column means

```
avgs <- colMeans(mat_colsort)
```

Find the increasing order of column means

```
neworder <- order(avgs)
```

Reorder your matrix appropriately

```
sorted_matrix <- mat_colsort[,neworder]
sorted_matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    2    3    2    4
[2,]    3    3    4    5    6
[3,]    4    6    5    6    6
```