# Sort column average in Python

Tags: python, sorting

About year ago I wrote the same function in R. Now I want to do the same in Python: [Sort matrix column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485769/sort-matrix-column-in-r)
I created matrix:

```
7 3 2
3 1 6 
4 3 1
```

Next, I sorted all column ascending:

```
3 1 1 
4 3 2
7 3 6
```

Now I want sort columns ascending by average. The output would look like this:

```
1 1 3 
3 2 4 
3 6 7
```

My all code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.matrix([[7,3,2],[3,1,6],[4,3,1]])
a.sort(axis=0)
b = a.mean(0)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to turn `a` into an `array` rather than a `matrix`.

```
>>> a[:,np.argsort(np.array(a).mean(0))]
matrix([[1, 1, 3],
        [3, 2, 4],
        [3, 6, 7]])
```

This can also be written as:

```
>>> a[:,a.A.mean(0).argsort()]
matrix([[1, 1, 3],
        [3, 2, 4],
        [3, 6, 7]])
```

The code would then be:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.matrix([[7,3,2],[3,1,6],[4,3,1]])
a.sort(axis=0)
print(a[:,np.argsort(np.array(a).mean(0))])
```